# Classe javax.annotation.Nullable não encontrada

Tags: java

Estou utilizando o JDK 8 e eu preciso utilizar a biblioteca `javax.annotation.Nullable`, mas o eclipse retorna um erro dizendo que não exite..

Alguém sabe como consegui-la ou qual a versão do JDK contém essa biblioteca?

Comment: Verifica nas JREs configuradas se de fato você está usando o JDK8. Menu Window > Preferences >  Installed JREs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta classe não pertence ao Java 8. Portanto, você precisa de uma [dependência](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305) externa para pode ter ela disponível no seu projeto.

Se estiver usando maven, você pode [adicionar ela desta maneira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031259/2387977):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: isso eu colocaria no meu codigo fonte?

Comment: @AdryanAlencar, você utiliza maven? Tem um arquivo `pom.xml` no seu projeto? Se não utiliza, você precisa do arquivo `jar` dentro do diretório do seu projeto (normalmente na pasta `lib`).

Comment: perdao, nao sei o que e maven rs

Comment: @AdryanAlencar, você tem um local no seu projeto com algumas bibliotecas (vários arquivos JAR)? Você pode baixar este JAR do FindBugs e colocar lá.